# Keras Dense layer gets input_shape wrong

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I wrote the below custom layer and when I try to add a Dense layer afterwards it gets the input_shape wrong and expects the shape[-1] dimension of the tensor before the layer.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Input


class SMSO(Layer):
    def __init__(self, feature_dim=256, **kwargs):
        self.feature_dim = feature_dim
        super(SMSO, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.scale = self.add_weight('scale',
                                     shape=(1, self.feature_dim),
                                     initializer='ones',
                                     trainable=True)
        self.offset = self.add_weight('offset',
                                      shape=(1, self.feature_dim),
                                      initializer='zeros',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(SMSO, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        x = x - K.mean(x, axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True)
        x = K.square(Conv2D(self.feature_dim, 1)(x))
        x = K.sqrt(K.sum(x, axis=(1, 2)))
        return self.scale * x + self.offset

x = Input(shape=(10, 10, 32))
l1 = SMSO(16)(x)
print(l1.shape)
l2 = Dense(10)(l1)
```

Here is the code to reproduce the error. l1.shape gives (?, 16) as expected but the next line fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a compute_output_shape function solves the problem.

```
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.feature_dim)
```

Any layer that modifies shape needs to have a compute_output_shape.